# Pass login information from PHP to AIR

Tags: php, android, air

I have a simple php login page. When user and password is correct i want it to pass the login information to air. I was able to do it when i used flash(passed values to swf file). But i can not figure out how to do it now, because the app is in android device and i have no idea how to reference it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say pass from PHP to AIR, do you mean that the user comes to your web app in the android browser, signs-in and then you want to launch the app with the user signed-in? In such a case you may pass the credentials in an encrypted string as a launch param to the AIR application. Register you app for a custom namespace, say **my-air-app://** and then pass the app the params.

In case you mean that you launch the sign-in page from your application using WebView and you want the app to pick them up - add a URL change listener to your webview object, from PHP redirect to a custom protocol, monitor this URI, once received, fetch and decrypt data.